# Services and ViewModels in Android MVVM - How do they interact?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-service, android-architecture-components

I've been using ViewModels from Android Architecture for some time now, and abide by never exposing the ViewModel to Context/Views (Android Framework/UI). However, recently I have run into an interesting problem.

When making a timer app, when a timer is started, a Service is run in the background running the timer. This way, when the application is closed, the timer still runs in the foreground in the notification bar until all timers have ceased. However, this means that all of my Timer objects and state are contained in this Service. My UI needs to be updated on each tick, but the Model doesn't necessarily need updated **How do ViewModels fit in with this scenario?**

Should the Activity receive LocalBroadcasts and notify the ViewModel every time? 
Should the UI state be read from Service->Activity->VM? It almost seems like the Service is the ViewModel, but this doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: How about `Service` updates data in `Model` observed by `ViewModel` observed by `View`. Same instance if that `"Model"` can be injected via `Dagger` for example.

Comment: In this case, the timer is ticking down every second. Each tick needs to update the UI if available, but not necessarily write to the Model layer. I will clarify this in the question and thank you for the suggestion

Comment: ~"**never exposing the ViewModel to Context/Views**".  You mean the other way around...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After some toying with different structures, the Service has found it's place in MVVM. What was throwing me off in this situation was thinking a Service shouldn't be started from a ViewModel and the fact that two repositories were necessary: Room Database to store Timers and a Service to represent the state of ongoing timers (onTick, play/pause status, etc). A ViewModel should not have any reference to views, but application context is OK. So starting the Service from a ViewModel is doable by extending the **AndroidViewModel** class. Here is the final structure:

**Model Layer**

- ***Service*** - Maintains a list of active timers, emits onTick() EventBus events, maintains active timer play/pause status. Ends itself once there are no active timers.
- ***Room Database*** - Stores timers for future use (name, total time, etc.)

**ViewModel**

- ***ViewModel*** - Listens for UI events, performs business logic, and emits EventBus posts. Any change in Model is communicated through the ViewModel

**UI**

- ***Activity*** - performs application flow tasks. Listens for relevant ViewModel communications to swap fragments/start new activities, etc.
- ***Fragment*** - handles animations and UI. Also notifies ViewModel of user interaction

Comment: Any sample source code would have complete the answer 100%

Comment: Why did you opt in for **EventBus** versus RxJava or Kotlin Coroutines?

Comment: At the time Kotlin Coroutines were still nascent. Today, Coroutines is a more solid route

Answer (score 8):

The services should be treated as AndroidViewModel which has application context in MVVM architecture.
Because, the service is doing something with the data as ViewModels do.

Services cannot talk directly to Databases. But it should talk to Repositories which intern talk to databases like SQLite/Room/Server.

As ViewModel has views like Fragment/Activity. Service transforms itself into Foreground Service with status bar Notification as it's view to update. We do not use LiveData for Notification's view, but update the notification itself (we can assume this as Activity/Fragment recreated).

Comment: I have not thought about it like this before. This just cleared up alot of my questions about Services in MVVM

Answer (score 2):

Instead of extending ViewModel, extend AndroidViewModel so that you can use the application context provided by AndroidViewModel. The application context is what you use in your Intent. You can then listen to clicks from the Activity of the ViewModel to start or stop the services in the ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    Application application;

    public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        this.application = application;
    }

    public void startService(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(application, ExampleService.class);
        application.startService(intent);
    }

    public void stopService(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(application, ExampleService.class);
        application.stopService(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't store context in view model.